# Need a Simple explanation of warm_start v/s parial_fit with example

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I read this on [the sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/glossary.html#term-warm-start)

> When fitting an estimator repeatedly on the same dataset, but for
>   multiple parameter values (such as to find the value maximizing
>   performance as in grid search), it may be possible to reuse aspects of
>   the model learnt from the previous parameter value, saving time. When
>   warm_start is true, the existing fitted model attributes an are used
>   to initialise the new model in a subsequent call to fit.
>
> Note that this is only applicable for some models and some parameters,
>   and even some orders of parameter values. For example, warm_start may
>   be used when building random forests to add more trees to the forest
>   (increasing n_estimators) but not to reduce their number.
>
> partial_fit also retains the model between calls, but differs: with
>   warm_start the parameters change and the data is (more-or-less)
>   constant across calls to fit; with partial_fit, the mini-batch of data
>   changes and model parameters stay fixed.
>
> There are cases where you want to use warm_start to fit on different,
>   but closely related data. For example, one may initially fit to a
>   subset of the data, then fine-tune the parameter search on the full
>   dataset. For classification, all data in a sequence of warm_start
>   calls to fit must include samples from each class.

I have written this code:

with `warm_start`:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(warm_start = True)
clf.fit(X_train_increment_1, y_train_increment_1)
clf.fit(X_train_increment_2, y_train_increment_2)
```

**accuracy  = 75%**

with `partial_fit`:

```
clf = SGDClassifier()
clf.partial_fit(X_train_increment_1, y_train_increment_1)
clf.partial_fit(X_train_increment_2, y_train_increment_2)
```

**accuracy  = 74%**

I want to know how does sklearn uses `warm_start` and `partial_fit` internally, when to decide which to use?

Comment: How are you are calculating accuracy?

Comment: i am calculating it by clf.score(X_test, y_test).  I am using same test set for calculating accuracy of both classifier

Answer (score 0):

When `warm_start=True`, the `.fit()` function will fetch the optimal `coef_` and `intercept_` in the regressor before undergoing `partial_fit`.